# thead not repeating in landscape print

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

When trying to print my table in landscape mode the thead doesn't repeat on each page. however, it seems to work fine in portrait mode. I can get it to work landscape if I remove a few div elements but I need the whole block. It might be worth noting the browser support im targeting is chrome/edge.

any ideas to get around this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Elbusta/tz2kc9jf/65/

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.print();
});
```

```css
tr {
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  padding: 3em;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

th {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="print">
print 
</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
            <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        </th>
        <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<button id="print">
print 
</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
            <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>body content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Might the amount of content in a single `<th>` cell be a reason for the browser not repeating it? Why do you have that much contents in a cell? That doesn’t seem right.

Comment: quite possibly, you can have multiple th elements within a thead right? maybe i'll try breaking it up a bit more. I have a feeling its to do with the space, It works if I set the page to A3 although it looks weird and still not really what I am after

Comment: You were right! replaced a div block with a th and set th display: block and it seems to have done the trick. This had me stumped for ages thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped. Could you try and formulate that in an answer to close this thread?